# Export/Import Pod entries in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I've moved my Wordpress site to another location. Importing the WP database worked fine, also importing the Pods structure. BUT, when importing the Pods data, the pod entries aren't included.

Anyone know how to export/import the individual pod entries?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution, it generates a csv for every pod type you have:

http://snipplr.com/view/53495/

The problem now would be importing it to the new wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for anyone looking for a PODS 2+ CSV importer.

http://podsframework.org/forums/topic/csv-and-mysql-importer-for-pods-advanced-content-type-tables/

The plugin accepts CSV files and other MySQL tables as source for import.  It works extremely well and I was quickly able to adapt it to a custom content use.

EDIT:
I have created a github repo for the plugin:
https://github.com/christowiz/pods-act-importer

Comment: please explain what was needed for use for Pods data. And if you can please share code snippets as the external link might brake in time when the plugin would change or be removed (rendering your answer useless)

Comment: This was a solution for a client to be able to import CSV data they generate monthly into a PODS database.  The plugin can import two kinds of data:  .csv files and internally between MySQL tables.

Comment: The link leads to a 404 page now.

Answer (score -1):

I made a plugin for this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/csv-importer-for-pods/

I will update with a new version soon.

Comment: Plugin page says this plugin closed due to a "Guideline Violation" in 2018.